# Play pause html5

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to get create a button to pause and play a video and change the innerHTML when clicked. This is what I've tried and I cant understand why it's not working. Can anyone help please:

```
function play() {
  var video = document.getElementById("video1");
  video.play();
}

var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");

playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

    if (video.paused === true) {
        // Play the video
        video.play();

        // Update the button text to 'Pause'
        playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
        // Pause the video
        video.pause();

        // Update the button text to 'Play'
        playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you try again to paste your code? Replace the current mess, select all the new code and then press the 'Code sample' button. Now it's full of 'enter code here' markers and the indentation is messed up. (Gary and I tried to fix it. Hope it's okay)

Comment: Also: "its not working" is not a sufficient problem description

Comment: Did you look into the debugger (console window) in your browser?

Comment: `video` variable is local to `play` function. It's not visible to the `click` event handler you assign later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
var video = document.getElementById("video1");
var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");

playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

    if (video.paused === true) {

        video.play();
        playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";

    } else {

        video.pause();
        playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
});
```